# can we take the $\alpha$ out of this equation $C = \frac{\alpha}{f_0} + \frac{\alpha}{f_i \times f_0}$

Tags: polynomials

i have the equation shown in the following:

$C = \frac{\alpha}{f_0} + \frac{\alpha}{f_i \times f_0}$

and the relationship between $f_0$ and $f_i$ is as follows

$f_i = f_0 + \alpha$

how can we write the above equation like in this way:

$C = \alpha \times {variables}$, during the variables, I dont want to include the $f_i$. Also, I dont want to inculde the $\alpha$ in the variables

is this possible?

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: Enclose your formulas by dollars

Comment: I edited your post to try and properly $\LaTeX$ify it.  Hope I got it right!  If not, feel free to re-edit it.  Cheers!

Comment: Your first expression is not an equation, it is a polynomial. Please check it.

Comment: @RobertLewis many thanks for your help, its first time to use this web.

Comment: @YanZong:  my pleasure my fried!

Comment: @RobertLewis Questions can possibly be unclear without LaTeX, and it's OP's responsibility to make his/her own question clear.  We may offer help though.  A better way to help OP is to show him/her the links to relevant [meta] post, like "[Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax... [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189)."

Answer (score 0):

Why, you're almost there; this is just $$ C = \alpha\left(\frac{1}{f_0} + \frac{1}{f_0(f_0+\alpha)}\right).$$

Comment: in the brackets， I also dont want to have the $\alpha$, espically in the Denominator, is this possible

Comment: @YanZong You didn't say that before; but that's only possible if you make some change of variables; or possibly through infinite expressions.

Comment: @YanZong no, not without a lot more information.